# SQL database experts: is this a bottleneck?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, profiling

I say no, partner says yes.  We are both stubborn. We will test but I need some ammunition from you to support my case that the below pseudocode is not that big a bottleneck.  What we are doing is running two queries.  The first is against a big table (100k records), called BigTable below.  Then, we take what we find (typically 30 or so records) and run these records (in a loop, see the second 'foreach' below) against a much smaller table, called SmallTable, typically having around 200 records.  My partner wants to combine the records found in SmallTable so they appear in the records of BigTable, but if you do this, you lose flexibility and the databases are no longer in normal form.  My partner says he does not care about Normal Form and claims the below is a bottleneck.  Help me win this battle!  Of course my fallback position will be "let's test it and see" but I could use some firepower now.  We expect between 10 requests a second (in which case probably the bottleneck, if any, is trivial) or up to 1500 a second (which probably will break our app somewhere else! LOL.  But we are optimists).

The platform: Microsoft SQL Server 2008, using web services written in C# and Linq-to-Entities (EF), running on a server remotely that we do not own, but owned by a server company like GoDaddy, on a 'Per Call' / stateless basis.  Everything set to default in SQL Server (e.g., Max Pooling = 100, Load Balance Timeout = 0, Pooling = True). I am not doing any caching, since I've read somewhere that caching does not work well with distributed databases, which I think this server company uses.

I appreciate it.  Here is the pseudocode:

```
Public  string MyWebMethod()
{

List<Record> myrecords = new List<Records>();

try  //try block 1
{
using (AEntityFramework context = new AEntityFramework())
{
var RecordsReturned =   (from x in context.BigTable
                            //some conditions deleted
            select x);

//do some stuff with these records, typically 30 records returned from BigTable, which has 10000 to 100000 records total

foreach (Record r in RecordsReturned)
{  myrecords.Add(r);} //add these records to the List myrecords, to be used later.

}

}
catch (Exception)
{
Try block 1 exceptions here
}
//end of try block 1
//////////////////  now move to the next SQL query, which loops--is this a bottleneck?

foreach (Record R in myrecords)
{
try  //try block 2
{
using (AEntityFramework context = new EntityFramework())
{

    var SmallQuery = (from y in context.SmallTable
                      //some conditions deleted
         select y); 

//small table has 100 to 200 records, it is very small

//do a short operation with the Record R and anything collected by var SmallQuery, typically 2 to 3 entries.


}

}//end of try block 2

catch (Exception)
{
//try block 2 exceptions here
}

} //end of foreach

return “OK”;
}
```

**[EDIT] in response to the answers to do a JOIN.  Failing an answer here I will open a second thread.  Thanks!  Have pity on a newbie pls.** 
Well I was afraid of this.  Now this question morphs and perhaps I'll open a new thread.

Here is my query:

- Table ACustomers (contains customer IDs, and zip codes)
- Table CCategories (contains categories like "food", "shelter","clothing")
  (linking) Table A_C (since Tables A and C are linked as many-to-many): contains "customer IDs" and categories, in combination as primary keys

I need to select all records in Table A that satisfy a condition, then filter these records depending on a list of parameters found in the linking Table A_C.  But I don't know what the length of the list of parameters is, ahead of time.  It varies method call by method call.

To give a concrete example

Table A has a list of "customer IDs" and "Zip Codes".  Table A_C has primary keys comprising "CustomerIDs" and "Categories".  Table C has "categories". I find the customers in Table A that live in a certain "Zip code".  Then, from this subset, I need to find which of these customers have selected certain products that fall in certain categories found in the linking table Table A_C: Food, Clothing, etc, but my web method does not know ahead of time what these categories are, rather, they are passed as a list: List myCategoryList (which could be 1 category or 100, varies method call by method call).

How do I write the projection using Linq-to-Entities?

```
   List<string> CategoryList = new List<string>() { "Food", "Shelter", "Housing" }; // in one call to the web service method

   List<string> CategoryList = new List<string>() { "Food", "Clothing" }; //in a second call--varies and I don't know ahead of time which is which.
```

So how can I do the projection using Linq-to-Entities?  I will open a second thread.

Comment: Why are you running SmallQuery inside the loop? Is there a condition (select) there? If so you need to include that in the "code"

Comment: Your stubborn partner also says you don't accept enough answers.

Comment: @Erwin: that's a really nice way of introducing someone to a relevant piece of FAQ! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general you're better off doing a join with all the records you are working on and dealing with them in one lot in your code. The DB server is probably quite stout and is optimized for doing combinations like this. It will be much faster than doing a 'pseudo-join' like it appears you're doing here (query, loop another query, etc).

Stick with the (possibly) 1st normal form. It will serve you better in the long run.

Comment: +1 (assuming we get some clarification of what's going on in SmallQuery)

Comment: I agree with @ethrbunny, the SQL server will perform the join fast as its optimized to do so, it will be faster than the c# code including the roundtrips... You did not give any info as per what your data is / query, but (guessing) you should look into using EF projection to create the combined result set.

Comment: @ethrbunny--thank you.  I will consider that, but the trouble is, I don't know Linq-to-entities well enough to do the Join, because the second query involves a couple of linking tables.  So given that ineptitude on my part, I guess your answer argues that my partner is correct, and that this is a serious bottleneck?

Comment: I'd agree that the code is a potential bottleneck - but your partner's solution isn't really ideal.

Comment: @ethrbunny: Did you mean 3rd normal form?

Comment: @PaulDecember: If you *can* get the same final result using a JOIN, you almost certainly *should* use the JOIN. Ignorance is no excuse; [RTFM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397908.aspx). Your partner is too dangerous to have a database admin login.

Comment: @everybody.  I will open a second thread but do give this a crack--it will save me time and I'll link the answer to the second thread (sorry I'm not yet good with stackoverflow).  I edit my question so it will fit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202847/simple-linq-to-entities-query-involving-include-i-believe  - this thread solved the problem, thanks to david. s.  Using the "contains" feature of EF4.0, which is new, I was able to do a "join" and resolve having to split the query into multiple steps.  So now I'm really going to win the debate with my partner! :-)